# Browser: hold "Alt" key focus on input text

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, alt-key

When user is typing in a html input text, is it possible to keep the browser from showing its menu when the user press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key deliberately or by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is @Runtis code modified just changed `e.keyIdentifier == "Alt"` to `18==e.keyCode`
http://jsfiddle.net/2dqCD/13/

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){    
    if(18 == e.keyCode && e.target.nodeName == "INPUT"){ 
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue=false)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2dqCD/

This checks to see if alt was pressed on an input node, in the fiddle, you can see it will still allow the alt key outside of the input box.

Hope this helps.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){    
    if(e.keyIdentifier == "Alt" && e.target.nodeName == "INPUT"){ 
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue=false)
    }
});
```

Comment: after alt pressed you have to type twice to get input focus

Comment: I am unable to replicate that, can you provide the browser and OS you are using? I am using windows 8.1 with google chrome 34.0.1847.131